# matlab function block does not respond

Tags: matlab, code-generation, simulink, matlab-coder

Im trying to use matlab function block of simulink to evaluate the value of a very long function that is like the one below (**but about 1.3 Mb**):

```
qdd24*((3*(cos(q22 + q23)*((7*sin(q25)*(sin(q21)*sin(q24) + cos(q22 + q23)*cos(q21)*cos(q24)))/125 + (7*sin(q22 + q23)*cos(q21)*cos(q25))/125) - sin(q22 + q23)*cos(q21)*((7*cos(q22 + q23)*cos(q25))/125 - (7*sin(q22 + q23)*cos(q24)*sin(q25))/125))*(cos(q05)*((26*cos(q21)*cos(q22))/125 - (49*cos(q21)*sin(q22))/1000) + cos(q05)*((507*cos(q21)*cos(q22))/1000 + (49*cos(q21)*sin(q22))/1000) + cos(q05)*((7*sin(q25)
...
```

where `qij` `qdij` and `qddij` are the inputs to the block.

but takes too much time to convert this block to C code when running simulation (almost never respond). is there any other way to evaluate this in a faster speed?

I also tried writing a function and call it using `interpreted matlab function` block but it gave me "Not enough input arguments" error.

Comment: Have you considered simplifying this algebraic expression using Mathematica or the like?

Comment: no Im not familiar with mathematica but Ive tried simplification using matlab it was very slow too.

Comment: how do you have a single function string that is 1.3MB in size? no wonder it takes so long. Also, it seems that everything is stored separately as different variables. This too is very frowned upon.

Comment: when I call the function in matlab itself(not simulink) it doesn't take much time but the c code conversion is slow. is there any way to use the matlab function without c code conversion or any thing similar.

Comment: I cannot comprehend how source code could be as large as 1.3MB. You need to describe how you got to that point. Forget about compiling that huge amount of code. Even if it was successful,  I do not want to imagine the kind of run time you would get.

Comment: it is generated by a matlab code for a robot dynamics (it is the computed torque for a link) I tried many ways to simplify it but i was not successful.As I said it doesn't take much time when calling the function in matlab (in millisecond order!) .

Comment: If possible split your code into multiple functions. Otherwise use coder.extrinsic to use your code in MATLAB function block without compiling.

Comment: @Navan How can I use coder.extrinsic?

Comment: Put your entire code in a separate MATLAB function (in a file e.g. foo). In matlab function block at the top add "coder.extrinsic("foo")". Then use foo normally and pre-allocate outputs of foo.